# Numpy "Place Object" in Array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a program where I am trying to generate outputs based on a few IO's--like these two IOs.[image: these two input outputs]

The program recognizes objects in the grids, and it represents the grids as numpy arrays. Is there a built in numpy function, or elegant solution, to 'inserting' an object into a numpy array?

Ex: if it recognizes a square object, like [[1, 1], [1, 1]], and I have a grid [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], how can I insert the object into the grid so it becomes [[0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0]] (but for any object inserted at any index)?

Comment: Assigning a block is easy, `arr[1:3, 1:3] = block`; just identify the target block with slices.  But doing the same with an irregular block would take a lot more work.

Comment: This could be doable by sparse arrays. From your example it looks like objects only ever are inserted such that they do not overlap. This would mean that adding objects to the [sparse array in coordinate format](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.coo_matrix) would be quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way other than knowing the indices at which to change the value of your 2-D numpy array.

So if your grid is a 2-D array of zeros like:

```
grid = np.zeros((10, 10))
```

Then you can use a tuple of indices tuples `(x, y)`, each identifying a cell of your grid at which you want to change the grid value:

```
indices = ((x1, y1), (x2, y2), ..., (xn, yn))
```

then you can use it to assign values in your 2-D numpy array like so:

```
grid[indices] = 1
```